# Tailwind colors from API call

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I've had a look around and there doesn't really seem to be an answer to this.

I have an CMS API that provides things like branding colors etc... for a React app that can "reskin" it's self using a mix of colors and images etc...

I'm working on a V2 of this app and want to switch from sass/scss to tailwind. With sass and scss we kind of just overwrote colors with CSS in JS and it worked pretty well.

In tailwind if you want to add a custom color pallet you need to create a config file etc... This will not work for my indented use as the colors will be changing on the fly.

Imagine a component:

```js
import { FC } from 'react';

const MyComponent: FC = () => {
  return <div className='bg-blue-500'></div>;

};
```

This works great however if I want to change the color as a one off I could use a classname like `bg-[#f1f1f1]` and this also works great!

However the issue seems to come if I get React to put this color as a template string, like so:

```js
import { FC } from 'react';
import { useBranding } from '../some_path';

const MyComponent: FC = () => {
  const [branding] = useBranding();  // custom hook, all you need to know is it has colours that it spits out colors
  
  return <div className={`bg-[${branding.colours.primary}]`}></div>;
};
```

At this point if I inspect the page I can see the color code goes in and should work. However I'm assuming that Tailwind has some preprocessing that get skipped if I do this?

Any ideas on how I can use colors in this way with tailwind?

Comment: Unless you're safelisting all of the potential class names this could produce then it will not work. https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tailwind doesn't detect classes after build.

I might be wrong as you're not showing how your hook works, but I'd say you can use style tag instead:

```js
import { FC } from 'react';
import { useBranding } from '../some_path';

const MyComponent: FC = () => {
  const [branding] = useBranding();  // custom hook, all you need to know is it has colours that it spits out colors
  
  return <div style={{backgroundColor: branding.colours.primary}}></div>;
};
```

Comment: yeah this would work, I just wanted to have it all nice and clean in one system, but this would work